# Store JSON files in local storage and implement full text search in flutter

Tags: json, database, flutter, full-text-search, local

I want to implement mobile app which will work without internet so that's why I have to store data in local storage. I have some nested json files. Also I have to implement search feature to search data like full text search from these json files. I am using flutter to create this app. Which database should I use to do above mentioned things.

I tried to use HIVE. I am able to store json files in it but there is no feature for full text search in it. How should I implement full text search for Hive.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **isar** database it has **full-text** search feature
and it's from the same author of **hive**

check this
https://isar.dev

Comment: Thanks @AbdullahAlamodi for you answer. Can I store json files directly in isar?

Comment: row JSON files is a string so surely you can store them.